# Issues in error handling in python

Tags: python, error-handling, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to bypass this error: `ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name u'No_Thanks'` error by using try..except statement. However, I am getting another error saying: `NameError: name 'ItemNotFoundError' is not defined`. I am not sure why is this happening. Thanks. Here is the code that I am using

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)')]
urls = "http://shop.o2.co.uk/mobile_phone/pay_monthly/init/Samsung/Galaxy_Ace_Purple"
r = br.open(urls)
page_child = br.response().read()
soup_child = BeautifulSoup(page_child)
contracts = [tag_c['value']for tag_c in soup_child.findAll('input', {"name": "tariff-duration"})]
data_usage = [tag_c['value']for tag_c in soup_child.findAll('input', {"name": "allowance"})]

for contract in contracts:
    if contract <>"Pay_and_Go":
        for data in data_usage:
            br.select_form('formDuration')
            br.form['tariff-duration']=[contract,]
            try:
                br.form['allowance']=[data,]
            except ItemNotFoundError:
                continue
            br.submit()
            page_child_child = br.response().read()
            soup_child_child = BeautifulSoup(page_child_child)
            items = soup_child_child.findAll('div', {"class": "n-pay-today"})
```

Comment: I'm guessing the exception is defined by `mechanize`.  Try:  `except mechanize.ItemNotFoundError` ...

Comment: @mgilson What I was going to say - I think it's part of the clientform part of it

Comment: @mgilson I think you should make that an answer ;)

Comment: @JonClements -- I don't have any idea.  I've never used `mechanize`.  I just figured that since it's being raised somewhere within `br` and `br` is a `mechanize.Browser` that it should be in there somewhere :)

Comment: @mist -- As a side note.  I've never seen the operator `<>` in the wild (though some of the people who've been using python longer than me probably have).  I'd suggest changing that to `!=`

Comment: @JonClements -- Posted it as an answer for your sake :) (I even downloaded and installed mechanize to test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the exception is defined by `mechanize`. Try: `except mechanize.ItemNotFoundError`

---

It appears that this is correct after installing mechanize:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> print mechanize.ItemNotFoundError
<class 'mechanize._form.ItemNotFoundError'>
>>> print mechanize.__version__
(0, 2, 5, None, None)
```

Comment: Huh. I must have an old version of mechanize (0.1.11) -- my `mechanize` does not define `ItemNotFoundError`.

Comment: @unutbu -- *shrugs* -- I was just guessing on this one until I experimented.  I don't really even know what mechanize is or does ... I printed my version as well for the sake of posterity :)

Comment: @unutbu -- They must have messed around a bit with `__init__.py` between version 0.1.11 and version 0.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code without the try..except you may get:

```
ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name u'No_Thanks'
```

So the error is defined in the `ClientForm` module. So you could catch it with

```
import ClientForm
....
        try:
            br.form['allowance']=[data,]
        except ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError:
            continue
```

---

If you want to catch a more general error, you could also catch it with `ValueError`, since `ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ValueError`:

```
In [10]: import ClientForm
In [15]: ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError.mro()
Out[15]: 
[<class 'ClientForm.ItemNotFoundError'>,
 <class 'ClientForm.LocateError'>,
 <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>,
 <type 'exceptions.StandardError'>,
 <type 'exceptions.Exception'>,
 <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>,
 <type 'object'>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module or the class defintion for ItemNotFoundError. It's not a standard Python exception, I guess it's an exception that is defined somewhere in the Beautifulsoup implementation but I'm not sure.

```
from some.module import ItemNotFoundError
....
except ItemNotFoundError:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade mechanize (python-mechanize)

> > > print mechanize.**version**
> > >       (0, 2, 5, None, None)
> > >       the imports working are now

Let's import some exceptions we'll need to catch later::

```
>>> from mechanize import LinkNotFoundError
>>> from mechanize import ItemNotFoundError
```